# C#: Generic members in non-generic types?

Tags: c#, collections, generics

I have a custom control which contains a list of objects.  The control is instantiated by the visual designer and then configured in code.  The control is a grid which displays a list of entities.

I have an initialise method like this.

```
public void Initialise(ISession session, Type type, ICollection<IPersistentObject> objs)
```

IPersistentObject is an interface.  However this doesn't work when I want to assign a collection of something that implements IPersistentObject.

So I changed it to this.

```
public void Initialise<T>(ISession session, Type type, ICollection<T> objs) where T : class, IPersistentObject
```

But now I want to assign the objs parameter to a member variable of type `ICollection<IPersistentObject>` which doesn't work.

I can't make the class generic because it is a control which can't have generic types AFAIK.  I can't copy the collection because the control MUST modify the passed in collection, not take a copy and modify that.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ICollection<T>` does not support generic variance like that. As I see it, your options are:

1. Code a wrapper around `ICollection<T>` that wraps a `ICollection<IPersistentObject>` and does the type-checking for you.
2. Use `IEnumerable<T>` instead, which does support variance in the manner you describe.
3. Use the non-generic `IList`, if your concrete classes implement it.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not need to the objs to be an actual collection (e.g. with `Add`/`Remove` methods etc..) then you could replace the `ICollection` with `IEnumerable`.

```
void Initialise(ISession session, Type type, IEnumerable<IPersistentObject> objs)
```

Comment: Sadly I need Add/Remove as the list will be modified by the control.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the member variable to a non-generic `ICollection`, and cast as appropriate.

Comment: This is not robust since `ICollection<T>` doesn't inherit the non-generic `ICollection` interface. There could conceivably be a type that implements the first interface but not the latter.